# margin, float not working in display flex

Tags: css

```
<div class="header">
  <h2>Records</h2>
  <div class="filter">
    <input type="text">
  </div>
  <button type="button">Filter</button>
</div>

.header {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/code_mouse/dqxu61pw/

http://prntscr.com/q51spr

I want to move the **filter div** element to the right.
But margin, float styles don't work.
What is the solution to move the central element to the right in **display: flex** ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option is to set `margin-left: auto` for the filter class

```css
.header {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.filter {
  margin-left: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <h2>Records</h2>
  <div class="filter">
    <input type="text">
  </div>
  <button type="button">Filter</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Update this HTML

```
<div class="header">
<div>
<h2>Records</h2>
</div>

  <div class="filter">
    <input type="text">
    <button type="button">Filter</button>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```css
.header {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <h2>Records</h2>
  <form class="form-inline">
    <div class="form-group">
      <input type="text">
      <button type="button">Filter</button>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```